# My app created on XP does not run on Windows 7

Tags: windows-xp, compatibility, windows-7-x64

I am trying to run an app I created at work (I sent myself the .exe file) so that I could see how it looks on Windows 7.

My laptop (running 64-bit Windows 7) won't even open it, though. It opens some compatibility wizard to try to rectify whatever the problem is, but that doesn't work either.

Is there anything I need besides the .exe itself, that I should have copied over?

A team member using Windows 7 can run it (by checking it out of Subversion and running it in the VS IDE, anyway), but the display if "off" (The FlowLayoutPanel's controls are experiencing a kind of "wardrobe malfunction"). But I, as mentioned, can't even run it.

What might be the problem/solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running the Professional edition of Windows 7 or higher then it will include the option to install the "Windows XP Virtual Machine". You can then run your app as normal under the virtual machine, quckest and easiest way to resolve these sort of issues in Windows 7.

Comment: My copy is "Home Premium" - I'm assuming that is "less than" Professional?

Comment: I did find this in the Googlesphere: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11060/create-an-xp-mode-for-windows7-home-versions-and-vista/

Comment: Will running in XP mode still give me the Windows 7 look/appearance, though? It's not that I just need to run an .exe on my Windows7 machine -- I need to say what my XP-compiled .exe looks like on Windows 7, and I'm wondering if XP mode would not give me a true "vision" of what it looks like under Windows 7.

Comment: @ClayShannon Home premium is not supported by default for the virtual XP machine. However to confirm, if you did manage to use this approach the application would look like windows XP and would not highlight how the app may look in a true windows 7 environment.

Comment: thanks, that's what I thought. AND, you need an XP CD/DVD to use the VMWare Player (which I don't), anyway. I copied everything from my \bin\Debug folder, and still get the same result - hourglass only, as it tries to start up, then nothing.

Comment: Are you able to go to the properties of the .exe file, then the compatibility tab and set it to run as compatible for XP?